# How to reduce the error on the graph to a minimum?

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```js
console.clear();
(function() {
  let data = getData();
  let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  window.onresize = draw;
  draw();

  function draw() {
 let vw = canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 30;
 let vh = canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 20;

 real_data();
 attempt();

 function real_data() {
   ctx.fillStyle = "black";
   data.forEach(function(p) {
  let cx = vw * p[0] / 100;
  let cy = vh - vh * (p[1] - 1061184077) / (1072693248 - 1061184077);
  point(cx, cy, 5);
   });
 }

 function attempt() {
   ctx.fillStyle = "orange";
   
   
   
   
   data.forEach(function(p) {
  let cx = vw * p[0] / 100;

  
  
  
  let percent = p[0] //Процент
  let y; // Число
  
  
      
      let err = Math.floor((100-percent)*1.5) ;//погрешность
    let err_2 = Math.floor((49.9-percent)*1.5) ;//погрешность
    let err_3 = Math.floor((24.6-percent)*6.7) ;//погрешность
    let err_4 = Math.floor((124-percent*10)*1.6-4) ;//погрешность
  if(percent <= 5){
  err_4 = Math.floor((50-percent*10)*2.6+25179+114) ;//погрешность
} else if(percent <= 3){
  err_4 = Math.floor((30-percent*10)*2.6+8393) ;//погрешность
}  
      let err_5 = Math.floor((30-percent*10)*2.6+8393)
      
      
      //let err_5 = Math.floor((50-percent*10)*2.6+25179+114) ;//погрешность 


  //let err = Math.floor((100-percent)*1.5) ;//погрешность
    //let err_2 = Math.floor((49.9-percent)*1.5) ;//погрешность
    //let err_3 = Math.floor((24.6-percent)*6.7) ;//погрешность
    //let err_4 = Math.floor(0) ;//погрешность
    //let err_5 = Math.floor((24.9-percent)+28) ;//погрешность  
    //let err_5 = Math.floor(((124-percent*10)*1.5)-1) ;//погрешность
      
  // console.log(err_5)
  let max = 1072693248
  let min = 1061184077
  
  let hund = 100
  
  
  let if_val_1 = hund-0.1;       // 99.9
  let if_val_2 = (hund/Math.pow(2, 1)).toFixed(1)  // "50.0"
  let if_val_3 = if_val_2-0.1       // 49.9
  let if_val_4 = (hund/Math.pow(2, 2)).toFixed(1)  //"25.0"
  let if_val_5 = if_val_4-0.1       //24.9
  let if_val_6 = (hund/Math.pow(2, 3)).toFixed(1)  //"12.5"
  let if_val_7 = if_val_6-0.1       //12.4
  let if_val_8 = (hund/Math.pow(2, 4)).toFixed(1)  //"6.3"
  let if_val_9 = if_val_8-0.1       // 6.2
  let if_val_10 = (hund/Math.pow(2, 5)).toFixed(1) //"3.1"
  let if_val_11 = if_val_10-0.1      //3
  let if_val_12 = (hund/Math.pow(2, 6)).toFixed(1) //"1.6"
  let if_val_13 = if_val_12-0.1      // 1.5
  let if_val_14 = (hund/Math.pow(2, 7)).toFixed(1) //0.8"
  let if_val_15 = if_val_14-0.1       //0.7
  let if_val_16 = (hund/Math.pow(2, 8)).toFixed(1) //"0.4"
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  
  let half_1 = 1050
  let starto = 2097
  
  
  
  let sum_1 = max - err - half_1
  
  
  
  
  let col_2 =  999 - 10 * (percent )
  
  
  let sum_2 = sum_1 - starto * col_2
  
  let sum_3 = sum_1 - starto * (999-10*(if_val_3+0.1)) - Math.round(starto*1.5)
  
  
  let col_4 =  999 - 10 * (percent + if_val_3 + 0.1   )
  let sarto_4 = starto * Math.pow(2, 1)
  let sum_4 = sum_3 - err_2 - sarto_4*col_4
  
    
  let col_4_5 =  999 - 10 * (if_val_5 + if_val_3 + 0.2   )
  let sarto_4_5 = starto * Math.pow(2, 1)
  let sum_4_5 = sum_3 - err_2 - sarto_4_5*col_4_5
  
  let sarto_5 =   Math.round(sarto_4_5*1.5);
  let sum_5 = sum_4_5 - sarto_5;
  
  
  
  
  
  
  let col_6 =  999 - 10 * (percent + if_val_3 + if_val_5 + 0.2   )
  let sarto_6 = starto * Math.pow(2, 2) + 1
  let sum_6 = sum_5 +err_3 -   sarto_6*col_6
  
  
  
  
  let col_6_7 =  999 - 10 * (if_val_7 + if_val_3 + if_val_5 + 0.3   )
  let sarto_6_7 = starto * Math.pow(2, 2) + 1
  let sum_6_7 = sum_5+ err_3 - sarto_6_7*col_6_7
  
  
  
  let sum_7 = sum_6_7 - Math.round(sarto_6_7*1.5)
  
  let col_8 =  999 - 10 * (percent + if_val_3 + if_val_5 + if_val_7 + 0.3   )
  let sarto_8 = starto * Math.pow(2, 3)
  let sum_8 = sum_7 - err_4 - sarto_8*col_8
  
  
  let col_8_9 =  999 - 10 * (if_val_9 + if_val_3 + if_val_5 + if_val_7 + 0.4   )
  let sarto_8_9 = starto * Math.pow(2, 3)
  let sum_8_9 = sum_7 - err_4 - sarto_8_9*col_8_9
  
  
  
  let sum_9 = sum_8_9 - Math.round(sarto_8_9*1.5)
  
  
  let col_10 =  999 - 10 * (percent + if_val_3 + if_val_5 + if_val_7 +if_val_9 + 0.4   )
  let sarto_10 = starto * Math.pow(2, 4)
  let sum_10 = sum_9 - sarto_10*col_10
  
  
  
  let col_10_11 =  999 - 10 * (if_val_11 + if_val_3 + if_val_5 + if_val_7 +if_val_9 + 0.5   )
  let sarto_10_11 = starto * Math.pow(2, 4)
  let sum_10_11 = sum_9 - err_5 - sarto_10_11*col_10_11
  
  
  
  
  let sum_11 = sum_10_11 - Math.round(sarto_10_11*1.5)
  
  let col_12 =  999 - 10 * (percent + if_val_3 + if_val_5 + if_val_7 +if_val_9 + if_val_11 + 0.5   )
  let sarto_12 = starto * Math.pow(2, 5)
  let sum_12 = sum_11 - sarto_12*col_12
  
  
  
  
  let col_12_13 =  999 - 10 * (if_val_13 + if_val_3 + if_val_5 + if_val_7 +if_val_9 + if_val_11 + 0.6   )
  let sarto_12_13 = starto * Math.pow(2, 5)
  let sum_12_13 = sum_11 - sarto_12_13*col_12_13
  
  let sum_13 = sum_12_13 - Math.round(sarto_12_13*1.5)
  
  
  
  let col_14 =  999 - 10 * (percent + if_val_3 + if_val_5 + if_val_7 +if_val_9 + if_val_11 + if_val_13+0.6   )
  let sarto_14 = starto * Math.pow(2, 6)
  let sum_14 = sum_13 - sarto_14*col_14
  
  
  
  
  
  let col_14_15 =  999 - 10 * (if_val_15 + if_val_3 + if_val_5 + if_val_7 +if_val_9 + if_val_11 + if_val_13+0.7   )
  let sarto_14_15 = starto * Math.pow(2, 6)
  let sum_14_15 = sum_13 - sarto_14_15*col_14_15
  
  
  let sum_15 = sum_14_15 - Math.round(sarto_14_15*1.5)
  
  
  let col_16 =  999 - 10 * (percent + if_val_3 + if_val_5 + if_val_7 +if_val_9 + if_val_11 + if_val_13+if_val_15+0.7   )
  let sarto_16 = starto * Math.pow(2, 7)
  let sum_16 = sum_15 - sarto_16*col_16
  
  
  
  
  
  let color19 = '#7d7d7d' // gray
  let color1 = '#ffa200' // orange
  let color2 = '#8f5b00'
  let color3 = '#fffb00' // yellow
  let color4 = '#7d7b00' 
  let color5 = '#bfff00'
  let color6 = '#6d9100'
  let color7 = '#15ff00' // green
  let color8 = '#0a7d00'
  let color9 = '#02f28a'
  let color10 = '#008a4e'
  let color11 = '#00fbff' // sky
  let color12 = '#008587'
  let color13 = '#0000ff' // blue
  let color14 = '#00009c'
  let color15 = '#dd00ff' // purple
  let color16 = '#5d006b'
  let color17 = '#ff00cc' // ping
  let color18 = '#9c007c'
  

  
  
  if (percent == hund) {
   y = max
   ctx.fillStyle = color1;
  } 
  else if (percent == if_val_1) {
   y = sum_1
   ctx.fillStyle = color2;
  }
  else if (percent >= if_val_2) {
   y = sum_2
   ctx.fillStyle = color3;
  }
  else if (percent == if_val_3) {
   ctx.fillStyle = color4;
   y = sum_3
  }
  else if (percent >= if_val_4) {
   ctx.fillStyle = color5;
   y = sum_4
  }
  else if (percent == if_val_5) {
  y = sum_5
  ctx.fillStyle = color6;
  }
  else if (percent >= if_val_6) {
   y = sum_6
   ctx.fillStyle = color7;
  }
  
  
  else if (percent == if_val_7) {
   y = sum_7
   ctx.fillStyle = color8;
  }
  
  
  else if (percent >= if_val_8) {
   y = sum_8
   ctx.fillStyle = color9;
  }
  
  
  
  
  else if (percent == if_val_9) {
   y = sum_9
   ctx.fillStyle = color10;
  }
  
  
  
  else if (percent >= if_val_10) {
   y = sum_10
   ctx.fillStyle = color11;
  }
  
  else if (percent == if_val_11) {
   y = sum_11
   ctx.fillStyle = color12;
  }
  
  
  else if (percent >= if_val_12) {
   y = sum_12
   ctx.fillStyle = color13;
  }
  
  else if (percent == if_val_13) {
   y = sum_13
   ctx.fillStyle = color14;
  }
  
  else if (percent >= if_val_14) {
   y = sum_14
   ctx.fillStyle = color15;
  }
  
  else if (percent == if_val_15) {
   y = sum_15
   ctx.fillStyle = color16;
  }
  else if (percent >= if_val_16) {
   y = sum_16
   ctx.fillStyle = color17;
  }
  
  
  else {
  ctx.fillStyle = color18;
  y = min + (max - min) * p[0] ** 0.35 / 3;
  }
  
  tef = 1
  ter = 5
  if (1 == tef){
   if (y-p[1] >= ter){
    ctx.fillStyle = "red";
        console.log(['red',p[0],y-p[1]])
   }
   else if (y-p[1] <= -ter){
    ctx.fillStyle = "brown";
        console.log(['brown',p[0],y-p[1]])
   }
  }
  
      

  let cy = vh - vh * (y - min) / (max - min);

  
  point(cx, cy, 3);
   });
 }
  }

  function point(cx, cy, r = 2) {
 ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.arc(cx, cy, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
   ctx.fill();
  }

  function getData() {
   return [
 [100 , 1072693248 ],[
 99.9 , 1072692198 ],[  //  100 - 99.9 ,  1050
 99.8 , 1072690101 ],[  //  99.9 - 99.8 , 2097
 99.7 , 1072688004 ],[  //  99.8 - 99.7 , 2097
 99.6 , 1072685906 ],[  //  99.7 - 99.6 , 2098
 99.5 , 1072683810 ],[
 99.4 , 1072681713 ],[
 99.3 , 1072679616 ],[
 99.2 , 1072677519 ],[
 99.1 , 1072675421 ],[
 99.0 , 1072673324 ],[
 98.9 , 1072671227 ],[
 98.8 , 1072669130 ],[
 98.7 , 1072667032 ],[
 98.6 , 1072664935 ],[
 98.5 , 1072662838 ],[
 98.4 , 1072660741 ],[
 98.3 , 1072658644 ],[
 98.2 , 1072656547 ],[
 98.1 , 1072654450 ],[
 98.0 , 1072652353 ],[
 97.9 , 1072650256 ],[
 97.8 , 1072648159 ],[
 97.7 , 1072646062 ],[
 97.6 , 1072643964 ],[
 97.5 , 1072641867 ],[
 97.4 , 1072639770 ],[
 97.3 , 1072637673 ],[
 97.2 , 1072635576 ],[
 97.1 , 1072633479 ],[
 97.0 , 1072631381 ],[
 90.0 , 1072484580 ],[
 89.9 , 1072482483 ],[
 75.0 , 1072170008 ],[
 74.9 , 1072167911 ],[  //  75.0 - 74.9 ,2097
 70.0 , 1072065150 ],[
 69.9 , 1072063052 ],[  //  70.0 - 69.9 ,2098
 65.0 , 1071960292 ],[
 64.9 , 1071958195 ],[  //  65.0 - 65.0 ,2097
 60.0 , 1071855435 ],[
 59.9 , 1071853337 ],[  //  60.0 - 59.9 ,2098
 55.0 , 1071750577 ],[
 54.9 , 1071748480 ],[  //  55.0 - 55.0 ,2097
 51.1 , 1071668788 ],[  // 
 51.0 , 1071666691 ],[  //  51.1 - 51.0 , 2097
 50.1 , 1071647816 ],[
 50.0 , 1071645720 ],[  //  50.1 - 50.0 , 2096
 49.9 , 1071642574 ],[  //  50.0 - 49.9 , 3146
 49.8 , 1071638380 ],[  //  49.9 - 49.8 , 4194
 45.0 , 1071437053 ],[
 44.9 , 1071432859 ],[  //  45.0 - 44.9 ,4194
 40.0 , 1071227338 ],[
 39.9 , 1071223143 ],[  //  40.0 - 39.9 ,4195
 35.0 , 1071017623 ],[
 34.9 , 1071013428 ],[  //  35.0 - 34.9 ,4195
 30.0 , 1070807907 ],[
 29.9 , 1070803713 ],[  //  30.0 - 29.9 ,4194
 25.0 , 1070598192 ],[
 24.9 , 1070591901 ],[  //  25.0- 24.9 , 6291
 20.0 , 1070180859 ],[
 19.9 , 1070172470 ],[  //  20.0 -19.9 , 8389
    
    
    
 15.0 , 1069761429 ],[
 14.9 , 1069753039 ],[  //  15.0 -14.9 , 8390
 
 
 10.0 , 1069136477 ],[
 9.9 ,  1069119700 ],[  //  10.0 - 9.9 , 16777
 9.8 ,  1069102923 ],[  //  9.9 - 9.8 ,  16777
 9.7 ,  1069086146 ],[  //  9.8 - 9.7 ,  16777
 9.6 ,  1069069369 ],[  //  9.7 - 9.6 ,  16777
 9.5 ,  1069052591 ],[  //  9.6 - 9.5 ,  16778
 9.4 ,  1069035814 ],[  //  9.5 - 9.4 ,  16777
 9.3 ,  1069019037 ],[  //  9.4 - 9.3 ,  16777
 9.2 ,  1069002260 ],[  //  9.3 - 9.2 ,  16777
 9.1 ,  1068985482 ],[  //  9.2 - 9.1 ,  16778
 9.0 ,  1068968705 ],[  //  9.1 - 9.0 ,  16777
 
 
 8.5 ,  1068884819 ],[
 8.4 ,  1068868041 ],[  //  16778
 
 
 5.0 ,  1068096289 ],[
 4.9 ,  1068062735 ],[  //  5.0 - 4.9 ,  33554
 4.8 ,  1068029181 ],[  //  4.9 - 4.8 ,  33554
 4.7 ,  1067995627 ],[  //  4.8 - 4.7 ,  33554
 4.6 ,  1067962072 ],[  //  4.7 - 4.6 ,  33555
 4.5 ,  1067928518 ],[  //  4.6 - 4.5 ,  33554
 4.4 ,  1067894963 ],[  //  4.5 - 4.4 ,  33555
 4.3 ,  1067861409 ],[  //  4.4 - 4.3 ,  33554
 4.2 ,  1067827855 ],[  //  4.3 - 4.2 ,  33554
 4.1 ,  1067794300 ],[  //  4.2 - 4.1 ,  33555
 4.0 ,  1067760746 ],[  //  4.1 - 4.0 ,  33554
 3.5 ,  1067592974 ],[
 3.4 ,  1067559419 ],[  //  3.5 - 3.4 ,  33555
 3.0 ,  1067400035 ],[
 2.9 ,  1067332926 ],[  //  3.0 - 2.9 ,  67109
 2.5 ,  1067064491 ],[
 2.4 ,  1066997382 ],[  //  2.5 - 2.4 ,  67109
 2.0 ,  1066728947 ],[
 1.9 ,  1066661838 ],[  //  2.0 - 1.9 ,  67109
 1.5 ,  1066385013 ],[
 1.4 ,  1066250796 ],[  //  1.5 - 1. 4,  134217
 1.0 ,  1065713925 ],[
 0.9 ,  1065579708 ],[  //  1.0 - 0.9 ,  134217
 0.8 ,  1065445489 ],[  //  0.9 - 0.8 ,  134219
 0.7 ,  1065269329 ],[  //  0.8 - 0.7 ,  176160
 0.6 ,  1065000893 ],[  //  0.7 - 0.6 ,  268436
 0.5 ,  1064732458 ],[  //  0.6 - 0.5 ,  268435
 0.4 ,  1064464023 ],[  //  0.5 - 0.4 ,  268435
 0.3 ,  1064086535 ],[  //  0.4 - 0.3 ,  377488
 0.2 ,  1063549664 ],[  //  0.3 - 0.2 ,  536871
 0.1 ,  1062769523 ],[  //  0.2 - 0.1 ,  780141
 0.0 ,  1061184077 ]    //  0.1 - 0.0 ,  1585446
 ];
  }
})();
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

In it, after each half of the total percentage, in other words, after each 100% 50% 25% 12.5%, the difference between the values doubles.

And at the intersection between 50.0% and 49.9%, the difference increases by 1.5 times.

plus everything after every 1% the number increases by 1.5.

I built a crude formula, but why am I constantly getting some kind of error.

Does anyone know where I made a mistake?

And how to reduce the margin error?

Comment: am I missing something or did you just post 12 pages of code asking to fix an error and not mention what the error is?

Comment: @Rick I wrote three patterns in the question that I found it. but after 50 percent that goes wrong and has to be used `if` but I don’t understand what is the reason

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what error you are getting, but one problem I see with you code: Not sure why you are doing any rounding in your math. always use floats, not ints with complex math. I would try removing all your rounding and "toFixed" references.

also, try breaking this code into smaller functions. you appear to have many pieces of code copy-pasted with small variations in each one. use DRY principles.